# Different results from DictionaryLookup, DictionaryWordQ and WordData

Tags: dictionary

It seems that the underlying dictionaries used by the three functions in the title are different. My ultimate question is "Why?"

As an example, I stumbled upon this set of results:

`DictionaryLookup["gage"]` returns `{gage}` (it recognizes the word);

`WordData["gage"]` returns `{{"gage", "Noun", "MeasuringInstrument"}, {"gage", "Noun", "Marihuana"}, {"gage", "Verb"}}`, though

`DictionaryWordQ["gage"]` returns `False`.

It seems that the last function is referencing a different dictionary than the first two (for what it's worth, `DictionaryLookup` works immediately; `WordData` loads a database before responding.)

This problem is referenced [in this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/169193/checking-if-a-word-exists), but the point of that question is different.

My question: why are there different (English) dictionaries?

Comment: For me, there are 2327 words that are in the dictionary but return `False` with `DictionaryQ`. Most of them are proper nouns and a lot of inflected forms but also things like "decompiler" or "voicemail". Hmm, hard to tell if this was made on purpose.

Comment: You should contact Wolfram Support and share their reply if meaningful.