# How to import unsupported language dictionaries?

Tags: import, natural-language, dictionary, word-cloud

Mathematica seems to only know about these 27 languages:

[image]

However, I need access to dictionaries for other languages, namely Romanian and Japanese. Now, `WordList` seems to only work for some of the above languages (not exactly sure which).

[image]

Can anyone help me find a convenient way to import dictionaries of unsupported languages?

**Update:**

One project I found that looked useful had many dictionary files: https://github.com/titoBouzout/Dictionaries.

However, I'm not sure what to make of Importing the `.dic` and `.aff` files:

[image]

Is this UTF8? What about diacritics?

Comment: `DictionaryLookup`and `WordList` work for other languages.

Comment: This may be worth a look at: [(169193)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/169193/764).

Comment: @gwr Can you provide an example of that with `WordList` for "Romanian" please?

Comment: @gwr if you post whatever your solution is for Romanian I'll accept

Comment: Another source can be found [here](https://github.com/wooorm/dictionaries). There are also links to tools working with these [Hunspell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunspell) dictionaries. So maybe the question is really: *How to make use of Hunspell dictionaries in Mathematica?*

Comment: Interestingly spell checking works for Romanian input. Try: `SpellingCorrectionList["săptamână", Language -> "Romanian"]` to get `{săptămâna, săptămână}` which also answers the question for glyphs or diacritics.

Comment: @gwr `WordTranslation["computer", "Romanian"]` works too